# ImportError: cannot import name 'Message' from 'exchangelib.folders'

Tags: python, python-3.x, exchange-server, exchangelib

I am using **Python 3.7 (x64)** on a **Windows 7** machine. I'm recieving the error message below, but when I did research on similar issues, none of the solutions appeared to relevant. The script is named **master_pdf_email.py**, and is inside a folder with no other .py files. This is on a newly reset computer and is the only other Py script installed, so there is no capacity for any email.py scripts to come into conflict with my current Python runtime.

- I checked to make sure that this is running on a new, cleanly installed Python distribution.
- I installed exchangelib 2.0.1 from pip on the same Python instance I'm using to run this.

Code up to when the error is thrown:

```
import pdfkit, mysql.connector, pprint, json, csv, datetime
from exchangelib import Credentials, Account, FileAttachment
from exchangelib.folders import Message, Mailbox
```

The traceback for the error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "master_email_pdf.py", line 3, in <module>
        from exchangelib.folders import Message, Mailbox
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Message' from 'exchangelib.folders'
    (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\folders\__init__.py)
```

Comment: From their [docs](https://pypi.org/project/exchangelib/) it appears you import `Message` straight from `exchangelib`

Comment: Fascinating. This code worked without any issues on one of the development machines. I want to do some research now and figure out how that could have happened.

Comment: Namespace can be manipulated depending on how you import.

Comment: If the solution answers your question please checkmark it and close this question out.

Comment: On pre-2.0 versions it just happened to work because `Message` was being imported into `exchangelib.folders` as a dependency. That changed in 2.0. It's actually located in `exchangelib.items`, but imported directly into `exchangelib` as a shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import directly from `exchangelib` for `Message` and `Mailbox`.

There is an example showing this on their [main page](https://pypi.org/project/exchangelib/).

If you look at the `__init__.py` for the primary `exchangelib` directory, you'll find that `Message` and `Mailbox` are being added to `__all__` which is where imports are loaded to the namespace. [[code](https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/blob/master/exchangelib/__init__.py)]

If you look at the `folders` [directory](https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/tree/master/exchangelib/folders) below that, you won't find any `Message` or `Mailbox` and within the `__init__.py` you won't find it either. You could get `MailboxAssociations` or `Messages` from `.folders` if that is what you actually need.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
The problem is that you have a script called email.py which overrides the built-in email module which then fails to import.

I created a new folder and moved my project to it , then my problem solved.

Comment: My python file was called email.py and renaming it solved this problem